# R- Create a single date from multiple columns

Tags: r

I hope I have a simple question for you all, but working with dates in R has been a difficulty for me

I have a time series data that looks like this

```
Month  Day  Year  Hour  Min  Sec Data
2       1    2012  1     0   0    56
2       1    2012  1     1   0    57
2       1    2012  1     2   0    52
2       1    2012  1     3   0    55
2       1    2012  1     4   0    57
```

My hope is to create a single date from the multiple columns and then plot the Data column by the date. My hopelessy oversimplified code would look like this:

```
Date1<-c(Month,Day,Year,Hour,Min,Sec)# For when hourly data is important
Date2<-c(Month,Day,Year) #For when daily data is important
as.Date(Date1)
as.Date(Date2)
plot(Data~ Date1)
```

I know it does not work, but I hope it can get the point across of what I am looking to accomplish.
Any ideas on how one might go about doing this?

Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want the `ISOdatetime()` function:

```
R> mytimes <- ISOdatetime(2012,1,2,1,2,c(3.123,3.456,3.789),tz="UTC")
R> mytimes
[1] "2012-01-02 01:02:03.122 UTC" "2012-01-02 01:02:03.456 UTC" 
[3] "2012-01-02 01:02:03.789 UTC"
```

And these are real `POSIXct` objects:

```
R> diff(mytimes)
Time differences in secs
[1] 0.333 0.333
attr(,"tzone")
[1] "UTC"
R>
```

I made my life easier here for the example and had just one argument vectorised. But with your data in a variable `mydf`, say, you could do

```
mytimes <- with(mydf, ISOdatetime(Year, Month, Day, Hour, Min, Sec))
```

and you should be set and ready for plotting.  You can also re-assign the `mytimes` column to the original `data.frame`.

Comment: Thanks Dirk- you rock! Works like a charm