# R - combine year, day of year, and 2400hr time into a single datetime

Tags: r, datetime, datetime-format

I have the following dataframe already read in to R called DF.

```
 V1,V2,V3,V4,V5
 2014,92,1931,6.234,10.14
 2014,92,1932,5.823,9.49
 2014,92,1933,5.33,7.65
 2014,92,1934,4.751,6.19
 2014,92,1935,4.156,5.285
 2014,92,1936,3.962,4.652
 2014,92,1937,3.74,4.314
 2014,92,1938,3.325,3.98
 2014,92,1939,2.909,3.847
 2014,92,1940,2.878,3.164
```

I am trying to simply plot the data using the datetime as the index on
the x-axis, but am having a hard time getting the datetime formatted
correctly.

V1 = year    V2 = day of year    V3 = 2400 time    V4 & V5 are the
values at each timestamp

I have tried to follow along these methods ([Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813270/r-create-a-single-date-from-multiple-columns), [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410273/combine-month-and-day-into-one-date-column))
but my day of year and 2400hr time formats are different and
therefore of no help to me.

I know this must be straightforward for those of you who know datetime
formatting well, but I am apparently not one of them! Thanks for your
assistance

Comment: Don't post data as images as they are useless for copying/pasting. What you had originally was better, just not formatted ideally.

Comment: I understand that, hence the apology. I tried many different ways of getting tyhe R output table into the agreeable form that SO wanted to blockquote or set it apart as a code block, to no avail.

Answer (score 3):

You can use strptime.

```
strptime(paste0(DF$V1, DF$V2, DF$V3), format = "%Y%j%H%M")
```

Comment: This returns `[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA`

Comment: `as.POSIXct(paste(DF$V1, DF$V2, DF$V3,sep="-"), format="%Y-%j-%H%M", tz="UTC")` - otherwise the values all run together and ruin the formatting.

Comment: Michele Useulli`s answer does not work, as Richard Scriven pointed out. thelatemail`s answer does. thanks